# Transporting an ADO .NET DataReader to and from a WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization, ado.net

I have a client/server sync tool that queries data on the client machine and sends it over to the server. The client is a WinForms app while th server is running a WCF service.

I've generated code to serialize all possible SQL data types to XML but was wondering if the ADO .NET DataReader can be sent over to the service directly (without requiring custom serialization).

The objective is to send over data to the WCF service without custom code handling various data types.

I tried adding various data types to the Wcf signature such as Exception, DataTable, etc. but these do not go through. Any guidance would be appreciated.

**EDIT**:
Based on comments, some clarification is in order. Both the client and server have NO knowledge of the underlying database schema on either side. Both only know the database name. They query the schema at runtime and whenever a table is found in common, a SELECT/INSERT statement pair is generated depending on which columns have the same name and data type. Having said that, I was wondering if there is a way to serialize the contents of the DataReader without writing custom conversion code.

Comment: Why don't you create a data contract and transform your datareader records to the data contract and send it over the service. It's not a good practice to send the full datareader over the Web. You might send data over via datareader that is not required.

Comment: @AzharKhorasany: Thanks. Please have a look at my edit which clarifies the usage scenario. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please look at this answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018847/c-sharp-sqldatareader-and-serialization